# The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to get the url to use the firebase storage image in my app

I have this method:

```
Future abc(ad) async{    
  final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(ad);
  var url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  print(url);
  return url;
```

I use a `final a = abc(snapshot.data[index].data["photo"].toString());`

```
ListTile(
              leading:Image.network(a),
              title: Text("Reporte de:"+snapshot.data[index].data["nombre"].toString()+snapshot.data[index].data["apellidos"].toString()),
              subtitle: Text("Fuga en:"+snapshot.data[index].data["colonia"].toString()+" cuya gravedad es:"+snapshot.data[index].data["gravedad"].toString()),
            ),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: abc is async, so it always returns a Future.  You have to await its results, just like you are awaiting getDownloadURL().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use await when you call abc and after that convert use a.toString() as an argument to Image.network

Because you are returning a future type so a will be of that type so you need to convert it to string type before passing to the Image.network